# python-How to set global variables in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm working on a `Flask` project and I want to have my index load more contents when scroll. 
I want to set a global variable to save how many times have the page loaded.
My project is structured as :

```
├──run.py
└──app
   ├──templates
   ├──_init_.py
   ├──views.py
   └──models.py
```

At first, I declare the global variable in `_init_.py`:

```
global index_add_counter
```

and Pycharm warned `Global variable 'index_add_counter' is undefined at the module level`

In `views.py`:

```
from app import app,db,index_add_counter
```

and there's `ImportError: cannot import name index_add_counter`

I've also referenced [global-variable-and-python-flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182963/global-variable-and-python-flask)
But I don't have a main() function.
What is the right way to set global variable in Flask?

Comment: Better place for global data in flask applications is the `flask.g` object, which is described here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.g

Answer (score 54, accepted):

With:

```
global index_add_counter
```

You are not defining, just declaring. So it's like saying "there is a global `index_add_counter` variable elsewhere," **and not** "create a global called `index_add_counter`". As your name doesn't exist, Python is telling you it can not import that name. So you need to simply remove the `global` keyword and initialize your variable:

```
index_add_counter = 0
```

Now you can import it with:

```
from app import index_add_counter
```

The construction:

```
global index_add_counter
```

is used inside modules' definitions to force the interpreter to look for that name in the modules' scope, not in the definition one:

```
index_add_counter = 0
def test():
  global index_add_counter # means: in this scope, use the global name
  print(index_add_counter)
```

Comment: Please note: While this makes sense for python requests, it might not make sense for Flask apps which can run in threads and workers. Defining a global like this might cause unexpected results when used in projection and you would be better off using a persistent data storage system like memcache or some other database. Depending on your use case this may or may not make sense.

Comment: @BenDog Your comment makes sense. What's the right way to do it?

Comment: Check this answer by @davidism on how to address several common scenarios where you need globals:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815451/are-global-variables-thread-safe-in-flask-how-do-i-share-data-between-requests